# Grouping DataFrame based on the limit fails based on PYTHON

Tags: python, pandas

i have data set similar to this

```
Parameter,LL,UL,DATA1,DATA2,DATA3
a,1,5,3,6,2
b,1,3,5,1,2
c,3,5,6,7,2
d,1,4,5,2,4,
e,2,100,45,76,14
f,2,200,23,45,67
g,300,23,56,78,90
h,200,400,300,345,350
i,300,500,400,401,4002
```

i need to group the data based on failures, suppose DATA1 is failing Parameters( a,b,f,) based on the limits(LL,UL), i need to categorize them into Category 1 say GRP1, like wise suppose if DATA3 is failing say( f,g,h) parameters, need to categorize DATA3 into some other category say GRP2..and if any DATA sets are failing similir parameters i need put them into same Category.
please help to provide coding ideas in python.

[enter image description here][1]

please refer to output for the [enter image description here][2]
i added 1 more column for better understanding, all GREEN colour passing limits and Yellow failing limits, DATA3 and DATA4 are failing same parameters , so i group them into same Group GRP3,and remaining 2 data are unique so i gave them GRP1 and GRP2.
i need to tag the data based on the based failed parameter

[enter image description here][1]

EXPECTED OUTPUT
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvEEW.png

code to check PASS/FAIL

```
l1=list(df.columns)
Data_name=l1[4:]

(r,c)=df.shape
dict={}
c1=0
c2=0

for j in range(len(Data_name)):
    
    for i in range(r):
        ll=float((df_temp.loc[i,'LL']))
        ul=float((df_temp.loc[i,'UL']))
        new_LL=ll
        new_UL=ul
        if (new_LL<=float(df_temp[[Data_name[j]]].iloc[i].values)>=new_UL):
            dict.update({Data_name[j]:"PASS"})
        else:
            dict.update({Data_name[j]:"FAIL"})
```

Comment: Thank you @Chris formatting nicely

Comment: Can you post your expected output based on the sample data along with what you have tried?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvEEW.png please refer to this link for expected output

Comment: added code to check pass/fail but not sure how to tag data based on failed category

Comment: Please refrain from using images or links. You can always post them directly to your question, just like how you provided your sample data ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, one way using `hash` after `pandas.Series.between`:

```
cols = df.filter(regex="DATA\d+").columns.to_series()
ss = [df[c].between(df["LL"], df["UL"]) for c in cols]
ss = [hash(tuple(s)) for s in ss]
new_df = cols.groupby(ss).ngroup()
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
DATA1    0
DATA2    1
DATA3    2
DATA4    2
dtype: int64
```

You can then format them as desired:

```
new_df = new_df.apply(lambda x: "GRP%s" % (x+1))
```

Output:

```
DATA1    GRP1
DATA2    GRP2
DATA3    GRP3
DATA4    GRP3
dtype: object
```

Which, again, then be used to rename existing columns:

```
df.rename(columns=new_df)
```

Output:

```
# Parameter   LL   UL  DATA1  DATA2  DATA3  DATA4
  Parameter   LL   UL  GRP1  GRP2  GRP3  GRP3
0         a    1    5     3     6     2     3
1         b    1    3     5     1     2     2
2         c    3    5     6     7     2     6
3         d    1    4     5     2     4     3
4         e    2  100    45    76    14    34
5         f    2  200    23    45    67    56
6         g  300   23    56    78    90    24
7         h  200  400   300   345   350   400
8         i  300  500   400   401  4002   640
```